# Assign new values to an array based on a function ran on other 3 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multiband raster where I want to apply a function to the values that each pixel has across all the bands. Depending on the result, a new value is assigned, and a new single-band raster is generated from these new values. For example if a pixel has increasing values across the bands, the value "1" will be assigned to that pixel in the resulting raster. I am doing some tests on an three dimensional array using numpy but I am not able to resolve the last part, where the new values are assigned.

The function to be applied to the 3 dimensional array is Trend(List). I have defined it in the begining. To be easier to iterate through the array values on the z (or 0) axis I have used np.swapaxes (thank you @Fabricator for this). The problem comes now when assinging new values to the new_band[i,j] array so that the result of Trend(List) over the list:

```
[myArraySw[0,0]] will be assigned to new_band[0,0]
[myArraySw[0,1]] will be assigned to new_band[0,1]
[myArraySw[0,2]] will be assigned to new_band[0,2]
[myArraySw[0,3]] will be assigned to new_band[0,3]
................................................
[myArraySw[3,3]] will be assigned to new_band[3,3]
```

Some values are assigned, but some not. For example new_band[0,1] should be "2" but is "0". The same with new_band[3,0], new_band[3,1], new_band[3,2], new_band[3,3] that should be "5" but they are "0". Other values look alright. Where could be the problem?

Thank you

Here is the code:

```
import os
import numpy as np

def decrease(A):
    return all(A[i] >= A[i+1]for i in range(len(A)-1)) 
def increase(A):
    return all(A[i] <= A[i+1] for i in range(len(A)-1))
def Trend(List):
    if all(List[i] == List[i+1] for i in range(len(List)-1))==1:
        return "Trend: Stable"
    else:
        a=[value for value in List if value !=0]
        MaxList = a.index(max(a)) #max of the list
        MinList=a.index(min(a)) #min of the list
        SliceInc=a[:MaxList] #slice until max
        SliceDec=a[MaxList:] #slice after max value
        SliceDec2=a[:MinList] #slice until min value
        SliceInc2=a[MinList:]  #slice after min value
        if all(a[i] <= a[i+1] for i in range(len(a)-1))==1:
            return "Trend: increasing"
        elif all(a[i] >= a[i+1] for i in range(len(a)-1))==1:
            print "Trend: decreasing"
        elif increase(SliceInc)==1 and decrease(SliceDec)==1:
            return "Trend: Increasing and then Decreasing"
        elif decrease(SliceDec2)==1 and increase(SliceInc2)==1:
            return "Trend: Decreasing and then Increasing"
        else:
            return "Trend: mixed"


myArray = np.zeros((4,4,4)) # generating an example array to try the above functions on
myArray[1,0,0] = 2
myArray[3,0,0] = 4
myArray[1,0,1] = 10
myArray[3,0,1] = 8
myArray[0,1,2] = 5
myArray[1,1,2] = 7
myArray[2,1,2] = 4

print "\n"
print "This is the original: "
print "\n"
print myArray
print "\n"
print "\n"

myArraySw = np.swapaxes(np.swapaxes(myArray,0,2),0,1) # swaping axes so that I can iterate through the lists

print "\n"
print "This is the swapped: "
print "\n"
print myArraySw
print "\n"

new_band = np.zeros_like(myArray[0]) # create a new array to store the results of the functions

for j in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
        if Trend(myArraySw[i,j]) == "Trend: increasing":
            new_band[i,j] = 1
        elif Trend(myArraySw[i,j]) == "Trend: decreasing":
            new_band[i,j] = 2
        elif Trend(myArraySw[i,j]) == "Trend: Increasing and then Decreasing":
            new_band[i,j] = 3
        elif Trend(myArraySw[i,j]) == "Trend: Decreasing and then Increasing":
            new_band[i,j] = 4
        elif Trend(myArraySw[i,j]) == "Trend: Stable":
            new_band[i,j] = 5
        elif Trend(myArraySw[i,j]) == "Trend: mixed":
            new_band[i,j] = 6

print "\n"
print "The new array is: "
print "\n"
print new_band
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least part of the problem is that when you typed:

```
    elif all(a[i] >= a[i+1] for i in range(len(a)-1))==1:
        print "Trend: decreasing"
```

you probably meant to type this:

```
    elif all(a[i] >= a[i+1] for i in range(len(a)-1))==1:
        return "Trend: decreasing"
        ^^^^^^
```

Also, if you don't mind a little unsolicited advice, the code you've posted has a pretty strong "code smell" - you're doing a lot of things in unnecessarily complicated ways.  Good on you for getting it done anyways, but I think you'll find this sort of thing easier if you work through some python tutorial problem sets, and read over the given solutions to see how more experienced programmers handle common tasks.  You'll discover easier ways to implement many of the elements of this and future projects.

Comment: Totally agree with you, thank you for pointing out the bad "print" statement. Although I am not a programmer I prefer to write code as much as I can (even if it is not the most efficient code) instead of asking people to write it for me...:).